# Enable strict mode only in development

Tags: android

I'm building an SDK and want to change stuff regarding strict mode when in development mode.

How can I know if I'm in develop mode in code?

Comment: What is your definition of development mode?

Comment: When i plug the device via usb and hit run/ run in emulator

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `BuildConfig.DEBUG` value, which is autogenerated by the ADT tools like R.java. It will always be true for non exported builds, and it will be set to false when you export a signed or an unsigned apk.

```
if(BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
   //In debug mode
}
```

Answer (score 10):

```
if(BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
   StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
   StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
}
```

or

```
if (DEVELOPER_MODE) {
         StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                 .detectDiskReads()
                 .detectDiskWrites()
                 .detectNetwork()   // or .detectAll() for all detectable problems
                 .penaltyLog()
                 .build());
         StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()
                 .detectLeakedSqlLiteObjects()
                 .detectLeakedClosableObjects()
                 .penaltyLog()
                 .penaltyDeath()
                 .build());
     }
     super.onCreate();
```

For more informations look at: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html

Answer (score -5):

On the Android phone use

- Settings->Applications->Unknown Sources - Enable it
- Settings->Development->USB Debugging - Enable it